# Inspect large linked database in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

This sounds like a quite simple and straightforward question, but I tried to search online and could not find an answer to my problem. I would like to view the linked database from Access but the database is too large and every step takes forever to load the data. I wonder if there is a better way to inspect the data tables? Sorry if this has been asked somewhere else, I am a bit new to Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have the program part (often called the front end (FE).

Then you have linked tables to the data file 9often called the back end (BE).

So, I can't say there necessary going to be much difference then just looking at the list of linked tables in the nav pane (FE).

Or, you can fire up access, and open the BE file. At that point, you will again see the "list" of tables in the nav pane. About the only difference here is that you as a general rule can't make changes to the table structure(s) in the FE.

But, other than that, the performance should not be much different. Of course if you are on a network and the BE is in some folder? Well then your network connection of course can and will effect performance.

So, in that case, what one often does is simply copy the BE from the server folder to that of a local folder. You can then open + use + play + consume that database (BE) 100% local on your computer without a network between you and the data file. This will of course run MUCH faster, and thus let you see/play and look at the tables and open them to see data inside such tables.

So, all in all? Copy the BE to a local folder. You be working on a copy of the data (that's safe - can't mess up production data), but certainly performance wise you find that any performance considerations should be quite much eliminated.

And for development and testing? Often we take the BE and place it on our local computer (say laptop) and thus work with that BE local. And depending on how the FE (program/software part) is setup, often it will have some options to re-link and thus you can point the FE to a different BE.

Just keep in mind that if you make changes to the BE? And you want such changes from that copy to appear or be made on the production BE? Well, you have to make notes, since there not really a automated way to send changes (say new tables, or changes to table designs) to the production BE. And of course, one has to be VERY careful. You can make changes to the tables such as re-name, or changing field names - that will for sure break the FE program part. You can in most cases of course add new fields/columns to existing tables, and that in most cases should not break your software.

But, from a performance point of view? I am somewhat perplexed you note performance issues and problems. Perhaps there is some VPN between the FE and BE (and that does not work well at all - you in general require a good solid network connection - a LAN (not a VPN/WAN) between the FE and BE. If a VPN (WAN) is to be adopted, then in most cases the BE needs to be migrated to sql server - the FE (program) part can then used linked tables to SQL server, and not a file based BE.

So while above should make sense - it is somewhat perplexing the performance issue you dealing with, or that you note here? (that does not quite make a whole lot of sense).

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you for the awesome answer. The data is on Oracle and Access is used within a system called Citrix. I was thinking about filtering data in Query Design to  quickly inspect data format but this was still very slow. I'm not sure if it was caused by network connection, but I think is quite likely the case. Much appreciate your insightful elaboration:)

Comment: Ok, kind of a "big" detail that the database is oracle. In that case - then yes, a LOT of queries will be slow. Thus in that case, then you can consider creating what is called a pass-though query. These queries send raw un-touched Oracle syntax to the server (so any query built this way will have to be 100% oracle syntax). These types of queries will run much faster. For a single table - not a lot of difference, but any kind of query with joins? Then the PT query will run much faster.